# How to convert geometry to WKB in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, well-known-binary

I have a shapefile with polygon type geometry. I want WKB format of the geometry values. Is there any such tool in QGIS so that without using gdal/ogr I can do this?

Comment: How you want to use it? As you can´t store it within the shapefile (beside already having it as binary in the .shp) you need another dataformat. A true WKB is also binary and would be safed as a raw byte datastream. The other option is a hexadecimal text-representation. There is a tool called "Plain geometry editor" that shows you the hex-WKB for the selected feature. If this is not what you need you only have the options using some python code or SpatiaLite. Both is built in QGIS but not a ready tool for an export.

Comment: I want to save it within the shapefile. May be in an added column. Binary or hexadecimal both format is fine. I can build the python or C code using GDAL/OGR. But I want to that is there any ready tool?

Comment: Within the Shapefile is not possible as the shapefile does not have the datatype blob (binary) and the text-type only has 254 characters max. And the wkb expression is way to long to fit into this.

Comment: Yes, when I tried to do the C code using GDAL, I also found this problem of 254 character-limit. But we have 'ExportToWKB' function for python, C, C++. Then, is this function for exporting the geometry to WKB formats and writing it to other file, not to shapefile?

Comment: Again, I did another thing. I imported my shapefile to postgresql database. There I found the hex format geometry. I just copied the hex format geometry to a new column of that same table. Then I exported this table to shapefile. There I found the hex values in the attribute table of the shapefile. So, how is this possible? Those hex strings are not that much large as it was point geometry. If the hex strings are more than 254 characters then would I have problem?

Comment: Now I have tried with a hex string geometry of more than 254 characters. I copied it to another column in postgresql. Then exported it to shapefile. And checked the attribute table. It is showing the hex string.

Comment: For points it might work, but after 254 characters it is cut off. Larger polygons won´t work. Its still not clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: But I tried with polygon. The copy technique worked

Comment: As you are using postgres try a char_length(your_wkb_column). All that are longer than 254 are broken when you export them this way. You will not be able to recreate a geometry out of it.

Comment: Ok. Got the point.